# Mutually Exclusive Events (Probability Theory)

Tags: haskell

Data.Set and Data.List have not a function for intersectionS.

As I was interested in mutually exclusive events, I wrote the following function.

Is it correct? Is it efficient?

```
mutuallyExclusiveEvents
  :: (Foldable t, Ord a) => t (S.Set a) -> Bool
mutuallyExclusiveEvents xss = 
    isJust $ foldr (\xs acc -> case acc of
                                 Nothing -> Nothing
                                 Just s  -> if any (`S.member` s) xs
                                            then Nothing
                                            else Just (S.union xs s)
                   ) (Just $ S.empty) xss
```

EXAMPLES

```
mutuallyExclusiveEvents [S.fromList [1,3,5], S.fromList [2,4,6], S.fromList [10,12,1]] == False

mutuallyExclusiveEvents [S.fromList [1,3,5], S.fromList [2,4,6], S.fromList [10,12]] == True
```

Comment: This should be posted on [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: `S.size (S.unions xss) == sum (fmap S.size xss)` might be the easiest way to do it.  (Doesn't shortcut on the first duplicate, if that matters.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a really good start. I think we can identify two goals:

1. we don't want our algorithm to be quadratic in the number of sub-sets
2. we want our loop over the input set of sets to truly short-circuit as soon as we determine there is overlap

We would fail at 1 if we tried the naive solution of checking the intersection of each pair of sub-sets in turn. In your solution you've recognized or intuited that if `s1` intersects with `s2` then it also intersects with the union of `s2` and `s3` so you can accumulate a union and check for intersection in one pass and save work.

You also partially succeed at (2) in that you avoid doing meaningful work as soon as you find an intersection. The only deficiency is you still have to traverse the entire list. We'd like `mutuallyExclusiveEvents` to truly short-circuit, that is it should work on infinite lists. A good way to test this when you're developing is using `undefined`:

```
*Main S> mutuallyExclusiveEvents' ([S.fromList [1,3,5], S.fromList [10,12,1]] ++ undefined )
*** Exception: Prelude.undefined
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at libraries/base/GHC/Err.hs:79:14 in base:GHC.Err
  undefined, called at <interactive>:95:93 in interactive:Ghci3
```

Due to laziness `foldr` (and other functions implemented in terms of it), `scanr` etc. can truly shortcircuit in the way that we want, e.g.:

```
*Main S> foldr (&&) True ([True, False] ++ undefined )
False
```

The trick is that if you want to be able to short-circuit when some condition holds, the function `:: a -> b -> b` you pass to `foldr` must be able to return a result without inspecting the second argument (of type `b`), i.e. it must be lazy in its second argument. Vice versa for `foldl`.

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
mutuallyExclusiveEvents
  :: (Ord a) => [S.Set a] -> Bool
mutuallyExclusiveEvents xss = 
  all nonOverlapping $ zip xss $ scanl S.union S.empty xss
    where nonOverlapping (s1, s2) = S.null $ S.intersection s1 s2
```

One way of looking at the functions above: `scanl` and `zip` are both *productive* ( inspecting the head of the resulting list only requires one step of evaluation) while `all` short-circuits in the way we've just been talking about.

Note it's less general than yours, working only over lists. I thought to rewrite it without `zip` but with scanl1 but was surprised to find that is not polymorphic in `Traversable` (there may be a good reason).

**EDIT**: also as you probably know you can likely get very sophisticated with your approach to this (and related) problems if you want to, especially if false-positives or approximations are okay, e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HyperLogLog